# Apache & PHP: secure directory permissions

Tags: php, apache, security, permissions

I was recently troubled by an injected spam script called `alias.php`. I’m still trying to work out how it got there, so I’m looking at directory permissions.

The parent directory of the offending file has the following permissions:

```
drwsrws---. 5 apache [group]
```

where `[group]` is the name of my group.

I don’t know whether weak directory permissions are the culprit, but, *just in case*, is there a more correct setup?

I’m running CENTOS 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you removing group permissions to write on the directory

```
drwsr-s---
```

To detect the culprit - check the owner of the file (I'm no CENTOS user, don't know the command) see if it's the root or a group member.

- If it's the root, someone has hacked you (I doubt it, though) and you have big issues to resolve
- If it's a group member then the above solution is for you, unless you need to add or modify the directory's files in the future

I hope I was useful.